# How can I use C to validate that the difference between two numbers is no more than X

Tags: c, validation, if-statement

I've pasted some code below to give a brief outline of what I'm writing. I basically need to say that if the difference between presentMeterReading and currentMeterReading is > 1000.. give me an error.

for example.

```
printf("Usage is high at over 1000");
```

```
if (presentMeterReading < 0 || presentMeterReading > 9999)
printf("That's out of range. Meter readings should be between 0 - 9999 \n");

if (previousMeterReading < presentMeterReading || presentMeterReading > previousMeterReading)

printf("Present readings should not be more than previous readings.");

if (dayReadingTaken > 12 || dayReadingTaken < 1)

printf("That's not a valid month.");
```

Comment: Learning is fine, expected even when you're here, so don't go and tag your posts "noob". That's irrelevant and demeaning.

Comment: `dayReadingTaken` implies that's a day, not a month.

Answer (score 1):

maths.

```
#include <math.h>


    if (abs(presentMeterReading - currentMeterReading) > 1000) {
        /* too much difference */
    }
```

Comment: Meters roll over. What if the previous reading is 9990 and the new reading is 30?